# defining ctype equivalent structure in python

Tags: python

I have a struct within a struct in the define.h file in this way:

```
typedef struct
{
 byte iVersion;
 long iMTPL;
 byte iMPR;
 byte iTempCompIndex;
 byte iTempCompRemainder;

} Message_Tx_Datapath;

typedef struct
{
 byte               iNumTxPaths;
 Message_Tx_Datapath datapath[NUM_TX_PATHS];
 } Message_Tx;
```

And I want to define an equivalent structure using ctypes in python for this so that when I use the dll I can pass this structure to fetch data in python.

How can I define this in python. I know how to define a single level struct but this is a struct within a struct and I'm not sure how I can define that. Please help.

Here's how I've started my code:

```
class Message_Tx(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_ = [("iNumTxPaths",c_byte),("datapath",????)]
```

Answer (score 1):

That would look something like this:

```
import ctypes

NUM_TX_PATHS = 4    # replace with whatever the actual value is

class Message_Tx_Datapath(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('iVersion', ctypes.c_byte),
                ('iMTPL', ctypes.c_long),
                ('iMPR', ctypes.c_byte),
                ('iTempCompIndex', ctypes.c_byte),
                ('iTempCompRemainder', ctypes.c_byte)]

class Message_Tx(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('iNumTxPaths', ctypes.c_byte),
                ('datapath', Message_Tx_Datapath*NUM_TX_PATHS)]
```

See the [ctypes documentation on arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#arrays).

Comment: I get the following error at compile: line 45, in FTM2LogMessage_LTE_Tx_AGC_Datapath
    ('iTempCompIndex', ctypes.c_byte),('iTempCompRemainder', ctypes.c_byte)]
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @emad Can you edit your question with some of the code around line 45?  In the small code snippet that the error gives I don't see any issues.